# linq to sql with stored procedure how to change display(UI) column name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have an ASP.Net MVC app using LINQ to SQL with a Stored Procedure.  I used the Visual Studio Object Relation Designer to create my model class.  Below is code of one of the properies. I want the name of my Grid(UI) to dispay 'Units Included' as the column header, with the space and no quotes.  I don't want the underscore.  Do you know how I can do this?  I have tried different attributes but can't get one to work.

Thanks

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage = "_additional_valid_units", DbType = "NChar(30)")]        
    public string Units_Included
    {
        get
        {
            return this._additional_valid_units;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._additional_valid_units != value))
            {
                this._additional_valid_units = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

---

Here is my .cshtml

```
@model HE.Web.Models.HuntDataOverview        

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "HD";
    Layout = "~/Views/SubTabOverview/_Criteria.cshtml";
}


@{          
    var grid = new WebGrid(Model.Results); 
 }  


 @using (Html.BeginForm()) 
 {        
     <div id="grid">          
        @grid.GetHtml()      
     </div>  
 }
```

This is from my controller:

```
 public ActionResult Results(OverviewSearchCriteria criteria)
    {
        StatisticsServices services = new StatisticsServices();            
        List<GetGMUOverviewResult> re = services.GetGMUOverview(criteria);

        HDOverview combine = new HDOverview();
        combine.Results = re;            

        return View(combine);
    }
```

Comment: What does your grid look like in your View?

Comment: I edited my original post to show how I'm displaying the results.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't necessarily find the answer but I have a simple work around.  First of all, the best research I could find indicated that this might be a .net bug, maybe.  However, to change the name of my webGrid all I need to do is not take the defaults from the model.  I did that by changing my webGrid as follows:

```
<div id="grid">

    @grid.GetHtml( 
    tableStyle: "grid", 
    headerStyle: "head", 
    alternatingRowStyle: "alt", 
    columns: grid.Columns( 
        grid.Column("GMU","THIS IS A TEST"),
          grid.Column("Units_Included"),
          grid.Column("min_req_res_points") 
    ) 
) 

 </div>
```

As you will notice that the first Column, I added the new column name "THIS IS A TEST".  Now I can name my columns whatever I need. FIXED!

Answer (score 1):

Add the DisplayNameAttribute to your property and it should work assuming you are using an helper that takes ViewModelMetaData into account.

```
[DisplayName("Units Included")]
public string Units_Included
{
}
```

Comment: I did try DisplayName but it didn't change the name of the column.  What do you mean by 'it should work assuming you are using an helper that takes ViewModelmetaData into account'?  How do I check that?  Thanks!

Comment: I edited my original post with the code used to display the results. Thanks